# How to trigger an event when row column crosses now()?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Is it somehow possible in postgres 12 to trigger an event when a table with an tsrange column crosses now(), or someone insert something that where the tsrange is prior to now()?

Triggers, as far i know, only triggers when someone insert or updates a row.

Triggering when someone insert a row which has passed now, seem to doable
With trigger that triggers on all inserts, but i am not sure how to trigger an event, when a given timestamp in that row crosses now..

And can both trigger scenarios be combined into one?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to schedule a program to run regularly and process the table.

Usually it is better to implement such logic in the `SELECT` statements.

Comment: So there is no way of making the database notfy the application connected to it, that an event has occured?

Comment: Time passing is no event.